# Django Template Page Outputting Nothing

Tags: python, django, json, templates, view

Can someone help me figure out why my Django template pages won't render anything?

I'm using Python Requests (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to retrieve JSON data from the external urls.  I decode the data by using .json(). This works as I would expect when executing this from command line, but when it does nothing in the view.

When I run the server, the page is blank. It has no title, no 'testing' printed, nothing.

My Template:

```
<html>
<head><title>Offer List</title></head>

<body>
<p>Testing</p>
{% load dictparser %}
{% for offers in network1_offers %}
{% autoescape off %}
    <div>
        <p>name: {{ offers|lookup:"name" }}</p>
        <p>pay: {{ offers|lookup:"payout" }}</p>
        <p>description: {{ offers|lookup:"description" }}</p>
    </div>
{% empty %}
    <li>Sorry, no surveys available.</li>
{% endautoescape %}
{% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

My View:

```
class OffersList(View):
    template_name="generic_app/offers.html"
    def load_offers(request):
        """
        import example network offers.

        """
        user = request.user
        user_agent = request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
        amparams = {'user_subid':user.sub_id, 'useragent':user_agent, 'user_ip':user.ip_address}
        examplenetwork = requests.get('http://example.com/api-get.php?pubid=00000&key=000000000000&mode=offers&incent=1', data=amparams)
        exampleoffers= examplenetwork.json()
        """
        import example network 2 offers.

        """
        clparams = {'subid':user.sub_id, 'ua':user_agent, 'geoip':user.ip_address}
        examplenetwork2 = requests.get('http://www.examplenetwork2.com/blahblah', data=clparams)
        exampleoffers2 = examplenetwork2.json()
        render(request, 'generic_app/offers.html', {'network1_offers':exampleoffers, 'network2_offers':exampleoffers2})
```

The url:

```
url(r'^dashboard/offers$', OffersList.as_view(), name="offers"),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing this because you haven't defined how to get to the `load_offers()` method in your view, currently your `load_offers()` method is just a method floating around in your class.

Using the base class `View` comes with it's methods that you need to implement, for example

```
class OfferView(View):

    template_name = "generic_app/offers.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return load_offers(request)
```

or much better change this to a `TemplateView`(because that's what it really is).

```
class OfferView(TemplateView): 

    template_name = "generic_app/offers.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(OfferView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['offers'] = load_offers(self.request)
        return context
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I'm unable to use request (load_offers(request) in your second example. Do you recommend a particular way to accomplish what I'm going for with TemplateViews?

Comment: You can access it via `self.request` - Updated the answer due since I had forgotten to add it.